# Catch Network Connection Events

Tags: networking, hot-spot

I want to run a script when i connect to a hotspot which have a login page that runs on first connection. I use that script in order to login automatically without my attempt.

I couldn't find which event to catch or which command or program to listen the connection statuses.

What should i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this to identify active network connections

```
lsof -i -P +c 0 +M
```

or

```
netstat -tlpn | sort -t: -k2 -n
```

Comment: Thanks, but; i need to trigger a wireless connection established event not remote response or requests.

Comment: You could have a look at http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl8_iwevent.htm -> iwevent. This will catch events generated by the hardware. Then you can parse the output in your script.

Comment: Yes, this is what i'm looking for. Thank you. :)

Comment: No problem. All the best.